# Cambiar automáticamente mes consulta sql

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, sql

soy bastante nuevo con sql y necesitaría un poco de ayuda por favor.
Tengo la siguiente consulta, lo que necesito es que el mes y el año cambie de manera automática según pasa el tiempo, para no estar todos los meses cambiando los datos.

```
SELECT C.codigo,    
   C.denominacionFiscal,estatus,
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC072019) AS 'FAC072019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP072019) AS 'REP072019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC082019) AS 'FAC082019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP082019) AS 'REP082019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC092019) AS 'FAC092019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP092019) AS 'REP092019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC102019) AS 'FAC102019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP102019) AS 'REP102019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC112019) AS 'FAC112019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP112019) AS 'REP112019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC122019) AS 'FAC122019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP122019) AS 'REP122019',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC012020) AS 'FAC012020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP012020) AS 'REP012020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC022020) AS 'FAC022020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP022020) AS 'REP022020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC032020) AS 'FAC032020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP032020) AS 'REP032020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC042020) AS 'FAC042020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP042020) AS 'REP042020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC052020) AS 'FAC052020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP052020) AS 'REP052020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.FAC062020) AS 'FAC062020',
   SEC_TO_TIME(T.REP062020) AS 'REP062020'
   FROM clientes C
   INNER JOIN usuarios U ON U.id= C.idConsultor

   LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT cliente,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 07 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC072019, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 07 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP072019,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 08 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC082019, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 08 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP082019,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 09 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC092019, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 09 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP092019,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 10 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC102019, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 10 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP102019,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 11 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC112019, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 11 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP112019,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 12 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC122019, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 12 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP122019,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 01 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC012020, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 01 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP012020,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 02 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC022020, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 02 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP022020,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 03 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC032020, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 03 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP032020,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 04 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC042020, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 04 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP042020,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 05 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC052020, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 05 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP052020,
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 06 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC062020, 
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 06 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2020 THEN horaReportadas ELSE 0 END))  as REP062020

       FROM customer
       WHERE gender in (1,2)
       GROUP BY cliente

   ) T
   ON C.codigo = T.cliente
   where C.estatus='Alta' ORDER BY C.codigo asc
```

Todo esta consulta va a acompañada de codigo PHP. Necesito cambiar los ultimos 12 meses.

Ejemplo: Actualmente es día 28/07/2020, necesito que la consulta me recoja los datos de los últimos 12 meses, Es decir hasta 08/2019. Cuando pasemos de mes y sea 01/08/2020 necesito que la consulta cambie automáticamente para que recoja los datos hasta 09/2019, sin que yo no haga nada.

¿como lo puedo hacer?, muchas gracias!

Comment: No se entiende el problema. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y explica lo que quieres hacer, lo que has intentado y que problema tienes en el código.

Comment: Ya la he editado, espero que ya se entienda porque llevo ya bastante tiempo con el problema sin sabes que hacer. Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Es muy fácil. Solo tienes que agregar otro criterio al `WHERE`, algo así más o menos: `AND ( YEAR(laColumna) BETWEEN YEAR(CURDATE())-1 AND YEAR(CURDATE()) ) AND ( MONTH(laColumna)=MONTH(CURDATE()) )` así te filtrará las fechas entre el presente año y el anterior del mes actual.

Comment: Perfecto, eso me ha funcionando bien, pero para intercambiar los meses como puedo hacerlo? Es decir para sustituirlo por variables. Y muchas gracias por la respuesta anterior

Comment: Tienes que explicar lo que quieres decir cuando hablas de *intercambiar los meses*.

Comment: @A.Cedano si te fijas en el `SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(CASE WHEN MONTH(fecha) = 07 AND YEAR(fecha)= 2019 THEN horaFacturables ELSE 0 END)) as FAC072019` me gustaria que el 07, 2019 y FAC072019 se intercambien por la fecha correspondiente. Es decir que si estoy en enero me coja hasta enero del año pasado. si estoy en agosto me coja hasta agosto del año pasado. Es decir siempre fechas de 1 año sin que tenga que cambiarlo mes a mes a mano por cada mes que pasa.

Comment: Pues lo mismo, usa algo como `YEAR(CURDATE())-1` por ejemplo, eso te dará `2019` este año y `2020` el próximo año y así sucesivamente porque resta `1` al año actual.

Comment: Saludos. Como mencionas que usas PHP; una opción es que en código PHP a partir de la fecha actual, generes los 12 meses; los guardes en un array, y entonces armes c/u de los `SUM` que tienes en el `LEFT JOIN (...) T`. Otra opción es que lo tengas en Store Procedure y allí igual en base a la fecha actual generes las fechas. Lo que puedo observar en tu código es eso de los alias que cambias, no creo a propiado esos alias cambien tanto.